# Pause setInterval if scrolling

Tags: ajax, scroll, setinterval

I have an infinite scroll pagination script, it’s included within a setInterval () function to append new data every x seconds, both functions work fine,  however every time I start scrolling I get the infinite scroll pagination corrupted once setInterval() refreshes the div, is there a way to prevent setInterval() from running as long as I’m scrolling?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    setInterval(function(){

        var track_load      = 0;
        var loading         = false;
        var total_groups    = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>;

        $('#live_activity').load("loading_page.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;});

        $(window).scroll(function() {

            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
            {
                if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false)
                {
                    loading = true;
                    $('.animation_image').show();

                    $.post('loading_page.php',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

                        $("#live_activity").append(data);

                        //hide loading image
                        $('.animation_image').hide();

                        track_load++;
                        loading = false; 

                    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                        alert(thrownError);
                        $('.animation_image').hide();
                        loading = false;

                    });

                }
            }
        });

    }, 3000);

});
```